# UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName doesn't work

Tags: ios, colors, uinavigationbar, swift3

I am trying to set the title color in my `UINavigationBar` in my `AppDelegate.swift`, like this-

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 26.0/255.0, green: 188.0/255.0, blue: 156.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Pacifico", size: 24)!]

    // Turquoise color rgba(26, 188, 156,1.0)

    return true
}
```

But it doesn't work. The result looks like [image: this]
Why isn't this working? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're overwriting the `titleTextAttributes` value you set initially with the color to a new value that includes only the font.

You should combine your attributes and then set them at once:

**Edit: Swift 4**

```
let color = UIColor.white
let font = UIFont(name: "Pacifico", size: 24)!

let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: AnyObject] = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: font,
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: color
    ]

UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attributes
```

**Swift 3**

```
let color = UIColor.white
let font = UIFont(name: "Pacifico", size: 24)!

let attributes: [String: AnyObject] = [
    NSFontAttributeName: font,
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color
]

UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attributes
```

Comment: I think you could probably do this a little more simpler, but this _did_ work. Thank you for explaining your answer as well as answering it!

Comment: @GeorgeB Yes it could be simpler (I realize I could have omitted the local variables altogether), but one of the main aims of the Swift programming language is to be very readable and clear.  As such, code brevity isn't always the best choice.  I also aim to be clear to stackoverflow readers who aren't as experienced with Swift and/or iOS and I think seeing a clear sequence of small steps can be helpful.  Thank you for accepting the answer, glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4:

For NavigationBar Background color:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 50/255, green: 90/255, blue: 150/255, alpha: 1)
```

For NavigationBar title color and font:

```
let attrs = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
    NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Georgia-Bold", size: 24)!
]

UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attrs
```

reference: [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-style-the-font-in-a-uinavigationbars-title)

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 4.2

```
let color = UIColor.white
let font = UIFont(name: "Pacifico", size: 24)!

let attributes = [
  NSAttributedString.Key.font: font,
  NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color
]

UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

**put code in your AppDelegate file**

```
let appTitlecolor = UIColor(red: 155.0/255.0, green: 204.0/255.0, blue: 67.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: appTitlecolor]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension UINavigationController {
    
    func appearanceNavigation(){
        
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 219/255, green: 57/255, blue: 66/255, alpha: 1)
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 219/255, green: 57/255, blue: 66/255, alpha: 1)
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, .font: UIFont(name: "PeachesandCreamRegularW00", size: 32)!]
        navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
        navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBar.standardAppearance
        navigationBar.compactAppearance = appearance.copy()
      

        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) { // For compatibility with earlier iOS.
            navigationBar.compactScrollEdgeAppearance = appearance.copy()
        
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).